# Get array of JSON string

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I want to parse a JSON string into my class object. Can you tell me what I am making wrong here?

```
public class Users
{
    public List<SteamUser> data { get; set; }
}

public class SteamUser
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string[] weapons { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var return_value = "{"user":"76561198005159244","items":["41750778","25316150"]}{"user":"76561198005159244","items":["41750778"]}";

        Users steamUsers = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Users>(return_value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, and doesn't generally look like C#. What have you tried doing so far?

Comment: i just want to get it parsed into an array, such like my EXAMPLE! never told that my code is working!! but i think every good coder is able to understand what i mean...?

Comment: When you post a question on SO, it should reflect your effort, and where you currently fail. We are not code generators.

Comment: i just don't know how to parse my json string to get every value into an array of arrays...so i have an array with userids and somewhere an array with items from the userid....could you please tell me how to parse the json in this example?

Comment: Suggestion: you can split by "[" and get  until "]", and than result you could split by ","

Comment: Edited! Maybe someone can help me now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your json string. You are mixing statements with string values. You should escape the `"` with a `\`if you are trying to construct a string.

```
var return_value = 
    "{\"user\":\"76561198005159244\",\"items\":[\"41750778\",\"25316150\"]}... etc";
```

Having said that, a way to check if your serialization and deserialization works, is to test it the other way round. Since you are using strong typed objects it's easier to generate valid json from the serializer.

Try this:

```
public class Users {
    //arrays are more supported
    public SteamUser[] data { get; set; }
}

public class SteamUser {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string[] weapons { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testObject = new Users() {
            data = new SteamUser[] {
                new SteamUser() {
                    id = "100",
                    weapons = new []{ "paper", "rock", "spock"}
                }
            }
         }; 

        //i am not familiar enough with the JavaScriptSerializer
        //but this should result in a proper json string   
        var validstring= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(testObject);

        //since you now have a valid string (Console.WriteLine(validstring);)
        //deserialization should always work
        Users steamUsers = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Users>(validstring);
    }
}
```

You'll now have a valid input for your deserializer, which you can use as an example.